# How to sample from a TextureCubeArray

Tags: winapi, hlsl

So I was surprisingly unable to find literally any information about sampling from a  texture cube array. In the mdsn docs, it states that the uv input for TextureCubeArray.Sample() is a vector4. This makes no sense to me. In 2d the uv goes from [0, 1] in 2 dimensions (x, y) and that is straightforward. In 3d, it's the direction which goes from [-1, 1] in three dimensions (x, y, z).

So what I'm straight up guessing, is that the w coordinate of a 4d uv also goes from -1 to 1. If this is true, then the w coord of the uv given a cubemap[i] from an array of size L is uv.w = (i / L) * 2 - 1 (+ eps?). Is at all correct? (Btw, I'm thinking you have to add the epsilon to account for the possible floating point error, or is the better way of doing all this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TextureCubeArray requires a vector3 for the sampling just like a TextureCube, but since it's an *array* of cubes, you need the index for the array.

For a TextureCube, you'd Sample it as:

```
sampler Sampler : register(s0);
TextureCube<float4> cubeMap : register(t0);

...

float3 envcoord = reflect(-eyeVector, worldNormal);
float4 color = cubeMap.Sample(Sampler, envcoord);
```

You have to use a `float4` for the TextureCubeArray where the `.w` is the cube index.

```
sampler Sampler : register(s0);
TextureCubeArray<float4> cubeMap : register(t0);

...

float3 envcoord = reflect(-eyeVector, worldNormal);
float4 color = cubeMap.Sample(Sampler, float4(envcoord, cubeIndex));
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up figuring this out after I posted it, but I appreciate the informative response :)